# Javascript transition implementation like as css

Tags: javascript, animation

there is point **a** and point **b**, you need to write an animation function that will animate the transition from one point to another in a certain time, as in css - transition ease-in-out 5s

```
 const start = Date.now();
const seconds = duration / 1000;
const fps = 1000 / 60;
const endpoint = 280 + seconds * 360;

let currentPoint = 0;

const loop = () => {
  const p = start + duration - Date.now();

  const angleStep = (endpoint - currentPoint) / (p / fps);

  let delta = currentPoint + angleStep < endpoint ? angleStep : endpoint - currentPoint;

  if (currentPoint < endpoint) {
    currentPoint += delta;

    wheelInstance.rotate(delta);
    wheelInstance.renderFrame();

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
};

loop();
```

NOTE! i can't use css in canvas

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-animate-a-straight-line-in-linear-motion-using-css/

Comment: no, i can't use css in canvas

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs that offer JS functions which essentially translate CSS properties, here is one:
[transitionjs](http://www.transitionjs.org/)

This is an example from their site for a simple transition:

```
function animate(element) {
    transition.begin(element, [
        ["transform", "translateX(0)", "translateX(200px)", "1s", "ease-in-out"],
        ["background-color", "#ffffff", "#ADB5C7", "500ms", "linear"]
    ]);
}
```

I've checked the API files, there are no CSS files.